# SqlDataAdapter not returning rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a `SqlDataAdapter` that I use to call a stored procedure that returns three result sets that are to fill a `DataSet`.

The adapter works great for the 2nd and 3rd result sets, but the first one only returns the schema and not any rows.

The stored procedure is written using a CTE to pull the first result set and calls two additional stored procedures for the 2nd and 3rd result sets.

Any thoughts or suggestions as to what I can check?  My thoughts are that the issue lies between the database and the C# app.  I am thinking that the `SqlDataAdapter` is having an issue with the CTE.

Comment: have you tried running the Stored procedure manually in SQL Server Studio or similar to just do a sanity check that you are getting the correct data returned?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue didn't lye in this section of code at all.  We were passing a parameter string that wasn't handled as expected.  The subsequent call to the database returned no rows because the parameters we had passed in the previous call were incorrect.